# is it possible to do the boolean in row by row in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to 'OR' between row and row+1

```
for example,
   A B C D E F G
r0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0
r1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
r2 0 0 1 0 1 0 1
```

and the expected output will be like this

```
result 0 1 1 0 1 1
```

I know only how to sum it.

```
df.loc['result'] = df.sum()
```

but in this case i would like to do OR

thank you in advance

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: yes, i would like to combine r0,r1,r2 by using 'OR' operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply `any` over the first axis.

```
>>> df
>>> 
    A  B  C  D  E  F  G
r0  0  1  1  0  0  1  0
r1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
r2  0  0  1  0  1  0  1
>>> 
>>> df.loc['result'] = df.any(axis=0).astype(int)
>>> df
>>> 
        A  B  C  D  E  F  G
r0      0  1  1  0  0  1  0
r1      0  0  0  0  0  0  0
r2      0  0  1  0  1  0  1
result  0  1  1  0  1  1  1
```

... assuming that in your output you forgot the last column.